# -SUID- Can't run a “-rwsr-xr-x” file as root

Tags: permissions, root, c

I am using Ubuntu 16.10. I just asked this question over at Stack Overflow but I was advised to ask at this forum.

I was following along a book, doing something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Real UID:\t%d\n", getuid());
    printf("Effective UID:\t%d\n", geteuid());
}
```

And to run this file as sudo without using the sudo command, after compiling with gcc, I changed the owner and group to root.

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ sudo chown root:root ./test
$ chmod u+s ./test
$ ls -l
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 8512 Mar 9 test
```

Now, this is what I got when I executed the file. My UID is 1000.

```
$ ./test
Real UID:        1000
Effective UID:   1000
```

The book I was reading said the result should be like this:

```
$ ./test
Real UID:        1000
Effective UID:   0
```

The UID for root is 0, right? Does this mean that I am running an *-rwsr-xr-x* file, owned by root, with my own user privilege? I don't understand.

Comment: Do you use an encrypted home directory? if so, see [Effective user id does not change after making the file owned by root](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18938648/4440445)

Answer (score 0):

You're likely putting the file on a partition that's mounted with `nosuid`. You can type `mount` to see if this is the case. If so, either move the file to a different partition or remount the partition with `-o suid` (note that doing the latter may have security implications).